# JSPM bundle doesn't load HTML files

Tags: html, bundle, jspm

I'm using jspm bundle command to bundle up all of my third-party libs.

```
jspm bundle app.js - [**/*] ./scripts/bundles/vendor.js --inject --minify
```

The bundle is created as expected.
For some reason when using the bundle my HTML stopped being loaded and I have no idea why.
In my config file I configured that all HTML files are to be loaded using the text plugin

```
meta: {"*.html": {loader: "text"}}
```

When using `depcache` option (without the bundle) or removing the bundle from the config file everything works fine.
The text plugin is in the bundle as well.

I'm using jspm v0.16.45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the reason this was happening, when bundling the text plugin the call for the HTML files comes before the plugin was loaded as part of the bundle.
just needed to take it out of there.